Failed to load PDF document from NetSuite Suitelet to generate PDF filename based on document number
I have some scripts to rename PDF file name and then create a custom button to download the PDF file of a transaction from NetSuite. It is based on the scripts supplied on this article - https://www.entartes.com/blog/workaround-netsuites-pdf-file-naming.
I have deployed this to several transaction types (quotes, sales orders, invoices, purchase orders etc. ) and it is working on all transactions except for Quotes. When clicking the custom button on a quote it is giving an error message that says "Failed to load PDF document"
Appreciate any help on this.

A couple of things to check:
this line:
pdfFile = render.transaction({ entityId: Number(params.id) });
may be failing if the customer does not have PDF format set as its preference. You can fix that by changing the code to:
pdfFile = render.transaction({ 
    entityId: Number(params.id), 
    printMode: render.PrintMode.PDF 
});

The other potential simple issue is whether or not your quote format prints normally. Can you open a quote and print it to obtain a PDF? If not check your logs for errors in the PDF template or in scripts that run when a record is being printed.
